# "cucumber foo.feature" not working from command line

Tags: ruby, git, bash, cucumber

I have been using `Jet Brains' Ruby Mine` for my `WATIR` project. But now because it is paid I want to use `Sublime free version`.

1. So I went to directory where my `.feature` file is.
2. Right click >> `git bash (MINGW32)` there.
3. I saw git command line tool opened
4. Typed `cucumber feature_file_name.feature` and it prompts me to write step definitions.

and I get this message at the bottom.
`If you want snippets in a different programming language, just make sure a file with the appropriate file extension exists where cucumber looks for step definitions.`

but they are already there and running fine in Ruby Mine.

What have I missed?

Comment: @AjitSingh for a beginner like me I cant understand what goin on there. And is that answers my `WATIR` problem?

Comment: The linked answer suggests that you likely need to tell Cucumber where your step definitions are. Where are your step definition files with respect to the feature file? Also note that this is a Cucumber problem rather than a Watir problem.

Comment: Try running the feature in the following format:

bundle exec cucumber --require path/to/step_definitions features/sample.feature

Comment: @JustinKo you meant like this `C:\Users\Admin\watircukepractice\NewProject>cucumber -r features/support/ -r features/step_definitions/ -r features/user_role_features/shopping_cart.feature` like this?

This indeed runs tests but does this command should be this long, looks not so appropriate to me.

Comment: The command is only long because you are trying to run a single feature file. Usually you would run all of the scenarios, which can be done by simply calling `cucumber`. If you really want to shorten it, look up "profiles". You could then do something like `cucumber -p min features/user_role_features/shopping_cart.feature`.